# How to reuse styles?

Tags: css

Back in the past I learned a lot about CSS but now I can't remember how to reuse styles.

Example:

I have some tabs with class `tab` and I can switch them with javascript. The current selected tab has another class, `active`.

Their CSS style:

```
.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}
```

Both styles has a lot of identic styles except 2, `cursor` and `background-color`.

So my question is, how can I resuse the .tab style and use it in .active?

I want achieve something like this:

```
.active { //extends .tab
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could, and probably should, apply both classes to the element like so:

```
<a class="tab active"></a>
```

If you want a css rule for the specific combination of these two classes, you'd do it like so:

```
.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.active 
{
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}

.tab.active /* no space */
{
    /* styles for elements that are both .tab and .active */
    /* leaving .active reusable for things other than tabs */
    /* and allowing override of both .tab and .active */
}
```

This allows you to avoid making unnecessary copies of your style declarations... and gives you the specificity to override either of the individual classes when an element has both.

Comment: No, then it would need both classes at a time, and that already does the "inheritance" for you.

Comment: Exactly, but you can gain specificity for overriding either of the other two classes.

Answer (score 15):

Do this.  Combine the styles and separate with a comma.  Then add other rules targeting the differences.

```
.tab, .active {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
}

.tab{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment

> I'm currently switching the tabs by adding .active style to the class
>   attribute.

this is what I would do:

HTML

```
<div class="tab"></div>
```

CSS

```
.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}
```

Then just add or remove the `.active` class, leaving the `.tab` as is.

As long as `.active` is *lower down* in the stylesheet, it will overwrite the necessary bits.

Comment: mmm what you say in the last sentence was probably the cause of my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use both class names in the `class` attribute. In the `.active` rule, define only different styles like you have already in the second example.

```
<div class="tab active"></div>
```

Comment: To expand a bit on the answer above, have your javascript _add_ the `.active` class rather than swap the classes.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.  They want to know how they can combine the styles in their stylesheet.  See the example.

Comment: I described best practice used in described scenario

Comment: @Jason Gennaro True. I'm currently switching the tabs by adding .active style to the class attribute. I just want to know how can I "extend" styles. The correct answer is as easy as delete the constant style attributes in active style. BUT by a weird reason, before posting this question this wasn't working O.o.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `.tab` rule to `.tab, .active`.

Answer (score 5):

```
.active, .tab {
   ... full style of both here
}

.active {
   ... the styles that differ from .tab
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This selector inheritance is a nice feature of [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

If you want to stick with plain CSS, look at the section on Selector Inheritance and you can see how the SASS code, with the @extend, is turned into regular CSS.

Comment: Of course it is worth. Very interesting. I liked the way they extend styles. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple classes to an element. So you can have an element with class = "tab active" and have it contain both specs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can extract base class with identic styles and mark your elements with two classes: `.tab .base`
2. You can use dynamic css language as [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) which supports classes inhritance

Answer (score 0):

You can combine .active into .tab and override the parts that need to change like this:

```
.tab, .active {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border: solid thin #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #272F42;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #FFCF75;
}
```