# Is there any way to use all css property and value to another css in one line?

Tags: html, css

Look at these codes:

```
.hero-text-box a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.8rem 10rem;
    background: #eb7d4d;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #c86a43;
}
```

I want to copy all property and value to another css selector. see the code below:

```
.row-3 input {

    .hero-text-box a 
}
```

Is this possible? or another way to do that?

Comment: read about SASS or LESS .. CSS cannot do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261823/how-to-reuse-styles

Comment: Why not add multiple selectors to the css, like .hero-text-box a, .row-3 input {}. Just separate with comma (,)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this.

However, you may use multiple selectors for a single declaration block though (separated by commas) This should achieve your desired result:

```
.hero-text-box a, .row-3 input {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.8rem 10rem;
    background: #eb7d4d;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #c86a43;
  }
```

More info on commas:
https://www.lifewire.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052

Other answers are referencing [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) which is an extension to CSS that has some additional methods of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using SASS, you can use @extend .hero-text-box a

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[@extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)** in SCSS. But can't extend nested selectors. So, you can't extend as `.hero-text-box a`. You can extend like this:

Input:

```
.hero-text-box {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.row-3 input {
  @extend .hero-text-box;
  color:red;
}
```

Output:

```
.hero-text-box, .row-3 input {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.row-3 input {
  color: red;
}
```

Or you can use **[@mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)**

Input

```
@mixin myProperties {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-text-box a {
  @include myProperties;
}

.row-3 input {
  @include myProperties;
  color: red;
}
```

Output:

```
.hero-text-box a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.row-3 input {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```